# Find common features between values of a dictionary two by two and store the result in another dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with values as type of list, I wrote the code as follows to find common features in all lists. I dont know how to find the common features two by two, comparing only two lists ? so if we have 3  in a dictionary, how to compare first and second values and then first and third and lastly second and third?  and store the result in a dictionary and generate the proper name for it as the key.

```
dic = {"df1":[1,2,3,4,5,555],"df2":[2,3,4,5,6,6,77,8,9,555],"df3":[1,2,2,3,4,5,6,76,7,555,5,4,3,2]}

from functools import reduce
dataframe_list = list(dic.values())
common = reduce(lambda a, b: set(a) & set(b), dataframe_list)
common
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
from itertools import combinations

out = {(a, b): set(dic[a])&set(dic[b]) for a,b in combinations(dic, r=2)}
```

Or as a more generic code (useful if you need combinations of more than 2):

```
from itertools import combinations
from operator import itemgetter

out = {x: set.intersection(*map(set, itemgetter(*x)(dic)))
       for x in combinations(dic, r=2)}

# or

from itertools import combinations

out = {x: set.intersection(*(set(dic[k]) for k in x))
       for x in combinations(dic, r=3)}
```

Output:

```
{('df1', 'df2'): {2, 3, 4, 5, 555},
 ('df1', 'df3'): {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 555},
 ('df2', 'df3'): {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 555}}
```

You can also simplify your original code to find the intersection of all values:

```
common = set.intersection(*map(set, dic.values()))
```

Output: `{2, 3, 4, 5, 555}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `set.intersection`

```
set.intersection(*map(set, dic.values()))
```

In use:

```
>>> dic = {"df1":[1,2,3,4,5,555],"df2":[2,3,4,5,6,6,77,8,9,555],"df3":[1,2,2,3,4,5,6,76,7,555,5,4,3,2]}
>>> set.intersection(*map(set, dic.values()))
{2, 3, 4, 5, 555}
```